# R: can extracted strings are saved into one column as separated characters?

Tags: r, string, extract

Let just say I need to assign classes to people based on sentences from comment line. (actual data is more complicated than this and I simplified it)
So I extracted strings from comment sentences from data using regular expression with remathces(), gsub() and gregexpr(). Then saved the list to columns and combined them as characters as below.

```
>cbind.data.frame(level,software,month,stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

   level                         software             month
1  c("beginner1","beginner2")    c++                  Dec       
2                      NA        Java                 Jan       
3             "beginner3"        NA                   May   
4         "intermediate2"        NA                   NA      
5                      NA        Matlab               Mar    
6             "advanced1"        c("java","c++")      Jul
```

and I would like to subset all characters into one column with

-breaking a list c("beginner1","beginner2") into "beginner1","beginner2"

-dropping NA

-remained as character  as below

```
  newcol
 "beginner1","beginner2","c++","Dec" 
 "Java","Jan" 
 "beginner3", "May"
 "intermediate2" 
 "Matlab", "Mar"    
 "advanced1","java","c++","Jul"
```

HOWEVER, when I combined, it was combined as one character.

```
> newcol<-unite(combined, newcol, 1:ncol(combined), remove=TRUE, sep = ",")

 "beginner1,beginner2,c++,Dec"  
 "Java,Jan" 
 "beginner3, May"
 "intermediate2" 
 "Matlab, Mar"    
 "advanced1,java,c++,Jul"
```

Is it possible to save multiple characters into one column as separated characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using

```
f <- Vectorize(function(u) {
  z <- unlist(regmatches(u,gregexpr('\".*?\"',u,perl = T)))
  if (length(z)> 0) {
    r <- gsub('\"',"",z)
  } else {
    r <- u
  }
  r
})

df$newcol <- apply(df,1,function(x) f(na.omit(x)))
```

such that

```
> df
                       level        software month                         newcol
1 c("beginner1","beginner2")             c++   Dec beginner1, beginner2, c++, Dec
2                       <NA>            Java   Jan                      Java, Jan
3                  beginner3            <NA>   May                 beginner3, May
4              intermediate2            <NA>  <NA>                  intermediate2
5                       <NA>          Matlab   Mar                    Matlab, Mar
6                  advanced1 c("java","c++")   Jul      advanced1, java, c++, Jul
```

where

```
> df$newcol
$`1`
$`1`$level
[1] "beginner1" "beginner2"

$`1`$software
[1] "c++"

$`1`$month
[1] "Dec"


$`2`
$`2`$software
[1] "Java"

$`2`$month
[1] "Jan"


$`3`
$`3`$level
[1] "beginner3"

$`3`$month
[1] "May"


$`4`
$`4`$level
[1] "intermediate2"


$`5`
$`5`$software
[1] "Matlab"

$`5`$month
[1] "Mar"


$`6`
$`6`$level
[1] "advanced1"

$`6`$software
[1] "java" "c++" 

$`6`$month
[1] "Jul"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(level = c("c(\"beginner1\",\"beginner2\")", NA, 
"beginner3", "intermediate2", NA, "advanced1"), software = c("c++", 
"Java", NA, NA, "Matlab", "c(\"java\",\"c++\")"), month = c("Dec", 
"Jan", "May", NA, "Mar", "Jul")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: This is amazing and thank you so much, but > str(df $newcol)  chr [1:6]   "beginner1, beginner2, c++, Dec" ...  so still  each row is read as one string, instead of "beginner1", "beginner2", "c++", "Dec".  So separated characters CAN NOT be stored in a column?

Comment: @rocknRrr could you `dput()` your data and I may have a try again if they can stored in a column

Comment: I wish I can share my data, but it's confidential... but my data has the same structure as you created, df. My understanding so far, it is impossible to store multiple, comma-separated characters into one variable(or cell) ..... Thank you so much!

Comment: @rocknRrr I think it is possible to store things in one cell. Please see my update

Comment: omg!!!! it's stored separately! you're genius, and appreciate your attention.

Comment: @rocknRrr I found there is no need to use `as.list` for the function within `apply`, which simplifies the code a bit. Please see my update

Comment: exactly as what I wished to create!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
A<-data.frame(a=c("a","b","c"),b=c("a","b","c"),c=c("a","b","c"))

apply(A,2,paste,collapse=",")
```

Comment: apply creates 3 columns, but I would like to put them into one column...

Comment: ```A<-data.frame(a=c("a","b","c"),b=c("d","e","f"),c=c("g","h","i"))

apply(A,1,paste,collapse=",")

``` with collapse=","